# http to https redirect for Login page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect the users of my application to HTTPS protocol when they visit Login page. The URL is of kind:

```
http://localhost/default/Login
```

I have written below Rewrite rule in my apache conf file (**Please note** that I want to do it from conf file only and not from .htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/Login$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This redirect is not working and I am not able to find out the reason. Have also tried printing **rewrite logs**, but not able to debug from that as well.

Please let me know what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Login [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

This rule solved my problem. Found out that `^` was for start of URL.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the code below to your httpd.conf file.

```
Redirect permanent / https://localhost/default/Login
```

See [Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html) for full description

Comment: Won't it redirect ALL the URL's to https Login page??. I just want to redirect my Login page to https and the other page should run on http.

Comment: It should only send that URI to https:, not the entire domain.

Comment: and how will it detect that it is Login URI and not any other?. RedirectPermanent redirects the whole domain URL's if you write it in conf file (under your virtual domain).

Comment: The rewrite rule that i have written is a 301 status code redirect only, which is not working, and that is what the PROBLEM IS!